# Return data from React Function

Tags: reactjs

For example I have an field that needs to have an user selected, so I have another React component where I select there the value, so I have a state there, how can I send that data to the current Component I have.

Comment: In case the data needs to be sent from parent to child component, one may be able to use props (NOTE: ReactJS uses uni-directional data-flow). If the components are not parent-child, another idea is to move the state `up the hierarchy` to a module where both components may receive the state. Another idea is to employ one of several `state management` tools (for example: redux). And, I'm sure there are other ways too (may be `useContext` hook, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it.

- Lifting state up - [Documentation Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)
- Using React Context API - [Documentation Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
- adding that selected data to LocalStorage (can be done but not suggested) - [Article Link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-localstorage-with-react-hooks-to-set-and-get-items/)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value of that state as a prop:

```js
const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState();
...
return (
  <OtherComponent prop={selectedUser} />
)
```

and receive that prop on the other component

```js
export default function AnotherComponent(prop) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use props in share data between componet
   2).use redux